# Clarifying cross version behavior in Scala

Tags: scala, sbt, kind-projector

I wonder what is the difference between the two here:

```
addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" %% "kind-projector" % "0.11.3" cross CrossVersion.full)

// if your project uses multiple Scala versions, use this for cross building
addCompilerPlugin("org.typelevel" % "kind-projector" % "0.11.3" cross CrossVersion.full)
```

My understanding was that `cross CrossVersion.full` add the full Scala version to the library e.g.

```
kind-project_2.13.4:0.11.3
```

and that `%%` adds the Scala Binary version e.g.

```
kind-project_2.13:0.11.3
```

Hence I do not understand why we need `cross CrossVersion.full` with both `%` and `%%`. What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am pretty sure they are the same.

From [Overriding the publishing convention](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Cross-Build.html#Overriding+the+publishing+convention):

> crossVersion setting can override the publishing convention:
>
> - `CrossVersion.disabled` (no suffix)
> - `CrossVersion.binary` (_)
> - `CrossVersion.full` (_)
>
> The default is either `CrossVersion.binary` or `CrossVersion.diabled` depending on the value of crossPaths.

From [More about using cross-built libraries](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Combined+Pages.html#More+about+using+cross-built+libraries):

> These are equivalent:
>
> ```
> "a" %% "b" % "1.0"
> ("a" % "b" % "1.0").cross(CrossVersion.binary)
> ```

So eventually all it matters is the value of [`crossVersion`](https://github.com/sbt/librarymanagement/blob/develop/core/src/main/contraband-scala/sbt/librarymanagement/ModuleID.scala#L19).

In order to test the `crossVersion`, I created a simple task in my `build.sbt`:

```
lazy val getVersion = taskKey[Unit]("A simple task")
getVersion := {
  List(dep1, dep2, dep3, dep4).foreach { d =>
    val att = Seq(d.organization ,d.name ,d.revision ,d.configurations ,d.isChanging ,d.isTransitive ,d.isForce ,d.explicitArtifacts ,d.inclusions ,d.exclusions ,d.extraAttributes ,d.crossVersion ,d.branchName)
    println(att)
  }
}
lazy val dep1 = "org.typelevel" % "kind-projector" % "0.11.3" cross CrossVersion.full
lazy val dep2 = "org.typelevel" %% "kind-projector" % "0.11.3" cross CrossVersion.full
lazy val dep3 = "org.typelevel" % "kind-projector" % "0.11.3"
lazy val dep4 = "org.typelevel" %% "kind-projector" % "0.11.3"
```

The output of `sbt getVersion` is:

```
List(org.typelevel, kind-projector, 0.11.3, None, false, true, false, Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), Map(), Full(, ), None)
List(org.typelevel, kind-projector, 0.11.3, None, false, true, false, Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), Map(), Full(, ), None)
List(org.typelevel, kind-projector, 0.11.3, None, false, true, false, Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), Map(), Disabled(), None)
List(org.typelevel, kind-projector, 0.11.3, None, false, true, false, Vector(), Vector(), Vector(), Map(), Binary(, ), None)
```

As we can see, all of the modules are equivalent, except for `crossVersion`, which in both `dep1`, and `dep2` is `Full(, )`. Unlike the two others which are `Disabled()` and `Binary(, )`.

Comment: I like the details and accept it as an answer. However I’m still puzzle at kind projector folks intention. What where they trying to do exactly ?

Comment: @MaatDeamon, I am really not sure. Maybe opening a github issue to clarify that will make more sense. I cannot find the reason for that.

Comment: Good idea, will do ! Thx 

Comment: @MaatDeamon, If you open an issue please paste its link here.